# fs.readFile of a module, how do I know where it is?

Tags: node.js

I need the jquery source in my npm module that I built.

I originally did this:

```
fs.readFile("./node_modules/jrender/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", "utf-8", function(err, src){
});
```

However this doesn't work if you already installed jquery in your main project, it wont download and install it to this path.

How can I fix this?

- Either I check if this file exists in either place, then use the one that exists.
- Include a fixed version of jquery in the module
- Does `require()` allow you to view the source of the included javascript file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the location of the jquery file by looking in `module.children`

```
var s = require("jquery");

var jqfile = null;

for (var i = 0;i < module.children.length;i++) {
    if (module.children[i].filename.match(/jquery.js$/))
      jqfile = module.children[i].filename
}

fs.readFile(jqfile, "utf-8", function(err, src){
});
```